# OGIS Ole Db provider sample with read/write capability

Tags: arcobjects, c#, ogc, well-known-binary, ole-db

I'm trying to determine what level of effort would be required to develop an OGIS Ole db provider for ArcGIS.

There is a [sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000nsq000000) that is read-only.  I would like to be able to edit featureclasses in the ole db workspace using the out-of-the-box editing tools in ArcMap.  Plus, I would prefer to develop in C# instead of C++.

I see that there was an [effort to do this with zigGIS](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.postgis/11740), but it never was completed.

Does anyone know of sample code showing how to do this?

Comment: may I ask why you are you going the OLE DB provider route? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: did anyone find the solution to making the plugin writable? I implemented the ITable andd ITableWrite on Dataset, however the plugin workspace itself does not seem to offer any indication to ArcGIS framework that it is write-able or read-only

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/82376)

Answer (score 1):

I have gone this route in the past. Honestly, unless there is an OLEDB-specific reason you need (like it needs to be able to be accessible from Excel), I would stay clear from it.

Instead, use the PluginWorkspace pipeline to add read&write datasets to ArcGIS. I have a [full-blown working one at my GitHub](https://github.com/RBURHUM/arcgis-ogr) written in C# which adds full GDAL/OGR support. You can edit it to suit your own case since it is Open Source.

Although that is read-only, you can add write support with a couple days more worth of work.

By the way, the ArcGIS documentation says that you can only do read-only through the PluginWorkspace pipeline. That is not true anymore. After [10.1 SP1 (see NIM083294)](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/ArcGIS101sp1-issues.htm), you can add write support.

How?

Implement ITable and ITableWrite on [your Dataset object](https://github.com/RBURHUM/arcgis-ogr/blob/master/src/OGRPlugin/OGRPlugin/OGRDataset.cs).

Pull-requests are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't realized that write capabilities was supported for Plugins.  That's the only reason I was looking at ole db.  I haven't downloaded your code yet.  Does "write" support mean I can edit using the standard editing tools?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall As far as I was told by ESRI, the answer is 'yes'. I have not done it yet because this capability has been there only since October/November.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with the plugin approach.  Still, just curious, would you happen to know if implementing an OGC ole db provider and registering it in an appropriate COM category would cause it to appear under the dropdown list of available database connections when adding a new SQL Query layer?  I'm not going to mark this as the accepted answer since it didn't really answer my question.  However it has been very helpful in my particular situation.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a particular component category for that. But honestly, the OleDB functionality was created prior to 2001 - it is not the right way to go

Comment: Ragi, great to know that write capability has been added!

Comment: I'll try to fork it and add some functionality.

Comment: Awesome @PetrKrebs! Looking forward to seeing those changes.

Comment: Okay, I tried to implement ITable and ITableWrite on the dataset, but no member of these interfaces ever gets called. ArcMap still says the layer is not editable. Perhaps there is something else which needs to be done?

Comment: Good changes. Thanks for the cleanup. Shoot me an e-mail and ragi at burhum com and we can debug this offline.

Comment: @PetrKrebs Also, if you can post the ITable & ITableWrite implementation in a branch, so I can see it. I found the cleanups on your branch, but no implementation of those interfaces. Good stuff man.