# Editing PostGIS database using ArcGIS for Desktop Add-In/Extension without ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-10.3

I need to improve an existing solution to be able to do **multiuser editing within a PostGIS database from ArcMap**.
Available for the solution is ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3 [Basic]. (No non-free Extensions or ArcGIS for Server)

There is already an existing solution implemented as an ArcMap-AddIn. It uses an editable exchange Format (Shapefile) which is read out to the database and updated from the database if there is a change in the Shapefile or PostGIS database.
This solution is prone to errors and needs to be improved.

I know it is possible to read from PostGIS databases in the new ArcGIS for Desktop versions using a query layer. But then the layer can't be edited.
The solution needs to be implemented as an Add-In or an Extension. Whatever is required.

As the “[ST-Links SpatialKit](http://www.st-links.com/)” is capable of such a connection. That's why I thought it might be possible to write a ArcMap Extension. Any Advice?

I know similar questions have been asked. But the questions and the answers I found, did relate to old versions of ArcGIS. There has been a lot of change relating PostGIS databases in the resent ArcGIS versions.

---

I found a clue to a good solution in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43646/ogis-ole-db-provider-sample-with-read-write-capability/43658#43658) answer to a different question.
It links to a coustom implementation of a "Plug-in Data Source" ([GDAL-Source](https://github.com/RBURHUM/arcgis-ogr)). It is a good example I could use as a template for my PostGIS implementation. But this solution didn't implement write support.
The same answer claims, write support for "Plug-in Data Sources" was introdused with version 10.1 SP1. My search didn't find any documentation for this. I can only find the old "read-only" [ESRI guidelines](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Plug_in_data_sources/000100000003000000/) for "Plug-in Data Sources".
In the lower part of the comments to the answer, Ragi Yaser Burhum and Petr Krebs try to implement write support. Sadly they didn't resolve there issues (at least publicly). I think [this](https://github.com/rburhum/arcgis-ogr/network) is a branch of their work.
Maybe anybody of you could point me to documentation (or a solution) for write support in a "Plug-in Data Source".